# The densities of alkanes increases gradually down the series as the molecular mass increases

Tags: grammar

Why the "increases" used as a plural? But before this "alkanes" had used as a plural.

Comment: please cite the source of this quote.

Answer (score 1):

"Increases" is not a plural, the word "increase" is being used as a verb, and it is in the third person singular form.

In the second use, that is certainly correct, as "molecular mass" is singular.  In the first case you could argue that the sentence should be "The density of alkanes increases..." or "The densities of alkanes increase..." So this use of "increases" can be considered an error, probably caused by a desire to use the same verb form in the two parts of the sentence.  In other words, it is an error caused by a complex structure.